# TCP Socket send data in GZIP Compression format

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am sending `MultiPart` content to my remote server to store it in filesystem. For this I am using Java `TCP/IP` protocol. For avoiding network bandwidth and TCP Input / Output buffer memory , I am sending the data in `GZIP` compressed format.  But , I cannot decompress the data received from the client. I got **`Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream`** Exception. Its due to the server is receiving data in **`chunks`**.

**Java Code**

**Client**

```
  OutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
  byte[] dataToSend = FileUtil.readFile(new File("/Users/bharathi/Downloads/programming_in_go.pdf"));
  out.write(dataToSend);
```

**Server**

```
    out = new FileOutputStream("/Users/bharathi/Documents/request_trace.log");
    InputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(clntSocket.getInputStream());
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    int bytesRead;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        out.write(buffer , 0 , bytesRead);
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }
```

Is there any solution to send the data in GZIP compressed format in Socket?

Comment: You might want to change your protocol to first send the size to read.

Answer (score 3):

GZIPOutputStream generates a `GZIP file format`, meaning that the other end has to receive the complete stream (which is a file) before it can process it, this is the reason for your error.

If you are looking to actually do a stream based data transfer, drop gzip, and go for zlib, I believe [Zlib compression Using Deflate and Inflate classes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173920/zlib-compression-using-deflate-and-inflate-classes-in-java) answers how to do this.

Comment: It wont work for Socket streams. We receive data in  chunks. Solution would be , I have to wait for whole data to receive. In this case memory is my concern.

Comment: What won't work? Zlib? of course it will, Zlib works under Sockets see - http://javatechniques.com/blog/compressing-data-sent-over-a-socket/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
out.flush();
sock.shutdownOutput();
```

to your client code.