# writing into file in a client and NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: java, file, exception, client-server, zipoutputstream

i have a server which sending thousands of tiny files like below:

```
static File file = null;

static File temp = null;
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket socket;


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{

    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Connected");



    File folder = new File("C:...\\Desktop\\thousands_of_tiny_files");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    File result[]=new File[listOfFiles.length];


    byte [] bytearray  = null;
    FileInputStream fin =null;
    BufferedInputStream bin = null; 



    for(int j=0;j<listOfFiles.length;j++){

        String path= listOfFiles[j].getPath();

        result=sendFile(path);
        for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++)   
        {
            fin = new FileInputStream(result[i]);
            bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin); 
            bytearray  = new byte [(int)result.length];
            bin.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("Sending Files "+ result[i]);

            os.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
            os.flush();

            System.out.println("File transfer completed");        

        }
    }
 fin.close();
 bin.close();
 socket.close();
}

public static File[] sendFile(String path)
{
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    File[] resultt = new File[listOfFiles.length];
    for(int i=0;i<listOfFiles.length;i++)
    {
        temp=listOfFiles[i];
        if(temp.isFile() && temp!=null)
            resultt[i]=temp;

    }
    return resultt;
}
```

it is successfull but my problem is in client side. i dont know how to distinguish between the files and write them seperately into the client.

**EDIT2:**
I changed the server side code like following using *ZipOutputStream* but still dont know how to unzip and **write** it in the client (mostly, dont know how to define the **FileOutputStream** in client:

```
    for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++)   
        {
            fin = new FileInputStream(result[i]);

            bytearray  = new byte [(int)result.length];

            ZipOutputStream zipOpStream = new ZipOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            zipOpStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(result[i].getName()));


            System.out.println("Sending Files "+ result[i]);

            zipOpStream.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
            zipOpStream.flush();

            System.out.println("File transfer completed");        

        }
    }

 socket.close();
}
```

and the reciever code:

```
          socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",3000);

         String outDir = "C:...\\Desktop\\here";



         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());            


          ZipInputStream zips = new ZipInputStream(bis);
          ZipEntry zipEntry = null;

          while(null != (zipEntry = zips.getNextEntry())){
          String fileName = zipEntry.getName();
          File outFile = new File(outDir + "/" + fileName);
          System.out.println("----["+outFile.getName()+"], filesize["+zipEntry.getCompressedSize()+"]");

    if(zipEntry.isDirectory()){
    File zipEntryFolder = new File(zipEntry.getName());
    if(zipEntryFolder.exists() == false){
     outFile.mkdirs();
    }

        continue;
    }else{
    File parentFolder = outFile.getParentFile();
    if(parentFolder.exists() == false){
     parentFolder.mkdirs();
    }
   }

   System.out.println("ZipEntry::"+zipEntry.getCompressedSize());



   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
   int fileLength = (int)zipEntry.getSize();

   byte[] fileByte = new byte[fileLength];
   zips.read(fileByte);
   fos.write(fileByte);
   fos.close();


        socket.close();

     }
```

now i get an exceptiom"negative **NegativeArraySizeException**"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at recieve.Reciever.<init>(Reciever.java:71)
    at recieve.Recieve$1.<init>(Recieve.java:28)
    at recieve.Recieve.main(Recieve.java:28)
ZipEntry::-1
```

which probably is because of

```
   int fileLength = (int)zipEntry.getSize();
```

but how can I solve this? i need the siz of next entry of zip folder for writing into the file.
but the size is in *Long* not *int*

Comment: Well you've just got a stream of data, with no indication of the length of each file. Consider using a length prefix before each file. (You should also use the value returned by InputStream.read - don't assume you will read the whole file in a single read call.)

Comment: @JonSkeet in fact it does perfectly. there are 2 files in each folder., everuy time i check if i meet a file or folder, then in the **send file()** will send it and then will read second folder until the end. but i wonder how the other side knows each file

Comment: Well that's what he said. It can't. You have to separate them.

Comment: I would concur with Jon on this. You can either initiate new connection for each file, which is more expensive or send the length of the file along with the rest of the data.

Comment: @EJP well done to state the obvious! how to seperate them?

Comment: Well done to *miss* the obvious, that @JonSkeet has already stated, again. "Consider using a length word prefix."

Comment: @EJP what if you look at the new issue?

Answer (score 1):

How about writing it into a ZipOutputStream where you can receive the file on the other side as a single stream. Once you have the entire output, you can write the reverse code to deflate the zip file and get all the files. Providing a sample code for writing the Zip into your socket stream, you can build your code over this.

Refer [this length](http://stick2code.blogspot.in/2014/05/send-multiple-files-over-single-socket.html) for a sample Server and Client implementation sending the file using a ZipOutputStream [Stick2Code](http://stick2code.blogspot.in/2014/05/send-multiple-files-over-single-socket.html)

Comment: ok, but how to unzip it in the client side? just replace the zipoutputstream with zipinputstream?

Comment: and last line of ur answer not correct, there is no method called **copy**

Comment: The IOUtils.copy was for illustruation, you are free to write your own code that will copy the bytes from the InputStream to the Zip output stream.

Comment: Import the IOutils belonging to the following package "org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils". This is available with the apache commons-io project version 1.3.2. Maven dependency     <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: AS for inflating the file back you could use the java.util.zip.Inflater. You can refer some of the documentation in following links. [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html), or the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173920/zlib-compression-using-deflate-and-inflate-classes-in-java)

Comment: my problem is" where should i save these files"? i mean, how to define **FileOutputStream** in client?

Comment: @user1064929: Updated a code to send and read a zip stream. Hope this helps.

Comment: @user1064929 : Have updated a blog with a working sample code for acheiving a transfer of file over tcp/ip, with parallel transfer to speed up the process. [Send Multiple Files over a single Socket Connnection](http://stick2code.blogspot.in/2014/05/send-multiple-files-over-single-socket.html) and [Transfer Files Between two Systems Over User Defined Ports](http://stick2code.blogspot.in/2014/06/transfer-files-between-two-systems-over.html)